# Edits to donut pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart, donut-chart

I am trying to add a legend, show counts not percentages next to the variable in the chart, and potentially have the percentages listed in the legend with the corresponding variable rounded to the nearest whole number.

This is what I tried:

```
PieDonut(PD, aes(Field, Status, count=n), explode=1, explodeDonut=TRUE, labelposition=1)
```

and this was the result

[image]

Here is the data:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput()` of your data instead of an image. Also, please indicate what package you have used to make your issue reproducible.

Comment: You may consider adding this as an issue for the package developer: https://github.com/cardiomoon/webr/issues